# Firefox - CSS Table TR/TD background issue

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've got a problem with table TR/TD background in Firefox. I've got table with dynamic content loaded via ajax. When I load content, I mark with green background some of the table rows. I attach a background to each TD in the row but when I check how it works in Firefox I get background only **under** text in td. (in chrome it's working very well on whole td size).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv3Z5.jpg

url to site: http://www.creas.pl/company/apps/moraman/Shipping/CzechRepublic

Table:

```
<table class="data-table" id="shippingTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="first last">
                            <th style="width: 20%;">Typ</th>
                            <th style="width: 45%;">Opis</th>
                            <th style="width: 15%;">Wartość zamówienia</th>
                            <th style="width: 15%;">Koszt transportu</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="loadShippingData" style="display: table-row-group;"><tr class="first last odd">
                            <td style="background: #EAF2D3;">My carrier</td>
                            <td style="background: #EAF2D3;">opis</td>
                            <td style="background: #EAF2D3;">10000.00</td>
                            <td style="border-right: 0; background: #EAF2D3;">5.00</td>
                            </tr><tr class="first last odd">
                            <td style="background: #EAF2D3;">Test</td>
                            <td style="background: #EAF2D3;">opis</td>
                            <td style="background: #EAF2D3;">10000.00</td>
                            <td style="border-right: 0; background: #EAF2D3;">99.00</td>
                            </tr>
    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Part of CSS:

```
.data-table {
    width: 100%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.data-table tr.odd.last {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
.data-table th, .data-table td {
    padding: 10px;
}
caption, th, td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Please show us code, not a link to the site. If we would open every link posted here we would get a lot of malware

Comment: thanks for fast answer. I understand Your point o view. I've posted most important parts of code because i have too much css files to put everything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-color` instead of `background`.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g478/). Your code works for me (chrome 32 + firefox 26 + ie > 8)

Comment: Thanks for help but still problem occurs on firefox.

Comment: well pure css on fiddle works like a charm. Can  ajax cause  problem with displaying data or I should look somewhere else ?

Comment: If your static code works fine then it's probably your dynamic code that causing the problem. Check what was changed and see how it affected your code/styling

Comment: Well thanks Itay Gal for help. I've checked and problem occurs when i load data with wrong css class...  ps. this community rocks =)